# preferred pattern for conditional execution of a Talend job

Tags: talend

I have a Talend job (call it A) that I want to run when an Oracle stored procedure (not executed by Talend) has completed.  I have an Oracle control table that I can check to see if the Oracle SP has finished.

I am imagining having my Talend job A run on a schedule - perhaps every 15 minutes - and the first thing that it would do is determine if A has already executed today.  If it has already run today it would stop execution immediately.  If it has not yet run today, it will check to see if the Oracle SP has completed, and if not, it will stop execution immediately.  This should result in Talend job A only executing once a day, and only after the Oracle SP has completed.

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: What causes the Oracle stored procedure to run? What extra information is in the Oracle control table? Does it time stamp the running of the sproc?

Comment: There is a cron job that runs the Oracle SP. And yes, the control table provides a starting timestamp for the SP, and a subsequent update of that row gives the status and timestamp, upon the completion of the run of the SP.

Answer (score 0):

As you've stated in the comments,  Oracle SP has a CronJob.
You should make a Talend Job (A) which will be executed shortly after the Oracle SP start. This would have an Iterate + tOracleInput-tJavaRow + tRunJob + tJava

```
Iterate (i<=80 && somevalue==1 --> tOracleInput - row1 - tJava --
         --IF--> row1.field.equals("true") --> tJava i = 101; --> tRunJob(JobB)
         --IF--> !row1.field.equals("true") --> tJava Thread.Sleep(15*60*1000);
```

This way when you execute the JobB you'll exit from the loop. Also your Talend Job will run once a day, and does the calculation once a day. I know it seems to be a little dirty but it will work.

Having i set to 80 you'll end up with 81 trys thats 20hour 15min for the worst case not counting the query runtime.

Thread.Sleep accepts miliseconds thats why you need to multiply by 1000 to get the seconds and 60 to get the minutes

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also think below options
1) export/build your talend job (A) as shell/batch file and execute it via same unix crontab job which executes your SP. You have to set dependency may be based on exit code of SP job.
OR
2) you can run your SP from talend job either using tOracleSP or even you can run your unix shell if any existing using tSystem and onSubJobOk run your talend job (A).
```